# Saber si pagina necesita permisos con qt5 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, qt5

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy haciendo un proyecto personal con qt5 en python3, y tengo un pequeño problema. Por ejemplo tengo este código que abre youtube al ejecutar el programa:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
 
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.browser = QWebEngineView()

    self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))

    self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

    self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":

  app = QApplication(sys.argv)

  window = Window()

  app.exec_()
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, si ejecuto eso no me da error y abre youtube bien, el problema viene cuando intento hacer una busqueda en youtube por el micrófono, ya que solo se queda esperando los permisos, me imagino eso mismo pasa con permisos como la cámara y el resto, ahora mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo saber con qt5 si una página necesita acceso a algo y darselo y negarle los permisos? Espero haberme dado a entender, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

proba este código, se puede mejorar el método __featurePermissionRequest .

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.show()
        self.__createConnections()

    def __createConnections(self):
        self.browser.page().featurePermissionRequested.connect( self.__featurePermissionRequest )
    
    @pyqtSlot()
    def __featurePermissionRequest(self):
        _url = self.browser.page().url()
        self.browser.page().setFeaturePermission( _url , QWebEnginePage.MediaAudioCapture, QWebEnginePage.PermissionGrantedByUser)


if __name__ == "__main__":

  app = QApplication(sys.argv)

  window = Window()

  app.exec_()
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).